# postgres, generated column from a jsonb columb, filtered

Tags: postgresql

i designed this table

```
CREATE TABLE mytbl (
    tags text[] GENERATED ALWAYS AS (tags (data)) STORED,
    data jsonb
);
```

with this function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tags (data jsonb)
    RETURNS text[]
    AS $CODE$
BEGIN
    RETURN ARRAY (
        SELECT
            jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'body') ->> 'value');
END
$CODE$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;
```

then i save into `data` jsonb column an object like this:

```
{
  "id": "#b709f4fa-fdce-423a-b760-5f0fed7d3393",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextualBody",
      "value": "Triangle",
      "purpose": "shapes"
    },
    {
      "type": "TextualBody",
      "value": "this is a comment",
      "purpose": "commenting"
    }
  ],
}
```

the `tags` field is populated correctly with all the values from `body` array.
but i need to exclude all the values where the purpose is `commenting`. how should i filter?

Answer (score 0):

Just filter them out.  This needs moving the set-returning function from the SELECT list to the FROM list.  But that should be done anyway as it is much clearer.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tags (data jsonb)
    RETURNS text[]
    AS $CODE$
BEGIN
    RETURN ARRAY (
        SELECT value->>'value' 
            from jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'body') 
            where value->>'purpose' != 'commenting'
    );
END
$CODE$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
IMMUTABLE;
```